# React How can I render complex array of data in DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I render in *DOM* in way to display all the orders for only specific restaurant name. 
So every restaurant will have Its own registered orders list.
My array looks like this:

```
[ { "_id": "5c6468c77982450218a95acf", "name": "Restaurant0", "location": "Tokio", "workinghours": 18, "user": "asa", "foodName": "Apple Pie", "orderDate": "25.02.2019.", "__v": 0 },
{ "_id": "5c6468c77982450218a95acf", "name": "Restaurant0", "location": "Tokio", "workinghours": 18, "user": "asa", "foodName": "Apple", "orderDate": "25.02.2019.", "__v": 0 },
{ "_id": "5c6468c77982450218a95acf", "name": "Restaurant1", "location": "Tokio", "workinghours": 18, "user": "asa", "foodName": "Apple Pie", "orderDate": "25.02.2019.", "__v": 0 },
 { "_id": "5c6468c77982450218a95acf", "name": "Restaurant1", "location": "Tokio", "workinghours": 18, "user": "asa", "foodName": "Fish sendvich", "orderDate": "25.02.2019.", "__v": 0 },]
```

Every restaurant in *DOM* needs to have its orders list.

Comment: What work have you done on it so far, show us your code and what isn't working.

Comment: Well, I have merged two arrays that I pull from mongodb server.  So now array looks like array that I posted here. Now i need ro render that array data in DOM maybe by using array.map. Also to mention I get that array from props in my component.

Comment: I need my render in DOM to looks like this on image link https://prnt.sc/mqhk6h

Comment: Good so far, then use `map` and if you faced problem there then come back with the relevant code

Answer (score -1):

depend if you have a class or function:
an example can be that:

```
const myComponent = (
<div>
  {myArray.map(item => (
    <div key={item._id}>
      <div>
        {item.name} " food: "{item.foodName}
      </div>
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

);
in return you can use the const as component:

{MyComponent}

Comment: I have already done that, but I dont need to render those restaurants that doesnt have any order. I need to display only those that have orders

Comment: so in your array there are some restaurants that have order?.. I use the array that you posted....anyway you can use if condition inside map... and render only that one that have order.... if you have some key order in your array....

Comment: So that is my problem. Map works fine, it reads restaurant by restaurant, and displaying that as a list. So now, It displays like this:
restaurant0
restaurant0
restaurant1
restaurant1

I need to read data first for restaurant0 then to go to the restaurant1 data.
I need to filter that somehow

Comment: I need It to be displayad in this way somehow like on this image: https://prnt.sc/mqurav